# jQuery ajax working in IE, Chrome, and FF...but not Safari (server using MVC 4)

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an MVC 4 application that is receiving data and returning a Json string back to the client. The code works flawlessly in Chrome, Firefox, and IE (only targeting 8+...but I have actually seen it work in IE7). It doesn't, however, work in Safari 5.x on Windows (I don't have a Mac...so I can't test that).

Here's the jQuery...(using 1.9.1...thx Tim B James for asking...forgot to mention it earlier)

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '@Url.Content("~/Request/ValidateApprover/")',
        data: { 'name': input },
        success: function (json) {
          //do some work here
        },
        error: function () {
          //tell the user that it failed here
        }
      });
```

And here's my Controller that is getting called...

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ValidateApprover()
{
  string emailAddress = "";
  string name = this.Request.Form["name"]; //<--the form is blank using Safari 5

  if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(name) || String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(name))
    return Json(new { result = "blank" }, "application/json", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

  //...keep going if you got a value other than blank
```

When I try to read the results in my Controller using `this.Request.From["name"]`, I am fine when using Firefox, Chrome, and IE...but I get a blank form value using Safari.

**EDIT 1:** I wrote a VERY simple PHP page to check and see if the data is being passed properly in Safari. It appears that it is...so it looks like something in between IIS and Safari is the issue.

**EDIT 2:** I wrote a very simple MVC Application to test and the data is coming across in that test....which leads me to believe it's some sort of HTML validation thing in Safari. I also removed the posted request header data in this edit.

Any additional ideas?

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: So how does the request headers and request (form) data differ between safari and, say, chrome? Also, out of interest, why don't you send it as JSON? You could also use ASP.NET MVCs built in model binding and validation too.

Comment: What's interesting is that I created a completely new MVC Application and it works...I duplicated the code to my original MVC Application and it fails. I am utterly confused as to why one would work and the other would not. :(

Comment: @Charlino They aren't different. They are the same. Identical. Nothing different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with Safari's handling of Kerberos authentication, but I have found a solution.

http://forums.iis.net/t/1182376.aspx/1

That thread on IIS describes that `Negotiate` (i.e. `Kerberos`) authentication is handled improperly in Safari. You have to disable `Negotiate` as a provider.

In IIS (I am using IIS 7.5), click your site, then `Authentication`(double click) → `Windows Authentication`(single click) → `Providers`(on the right side) → `Remove Negotiate and leave NTLM`

This fixed all my problems with Safari.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I use:

function setContent(contentfile) {

```
if (window.XMLHttpRequest){// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else{// code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4  && xmlhttp.status==200 ){
        //alert(xmlhttp.responseText);
      $('#*******').html(xmlhttp.responseText);
    }
}
xmlhttp.open("GET",contentfile,true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

}

it works in all browsers.

Comment: Does not work for POST (at least...not in Safari 5 with my IIS 8 server). Changed xmlhttp.open to `xmlhttp.open("POST", url, true);` then I ran `xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");`, then sent my encoded data using `xmlhttp.send(data)`. Works fine, data shows on the server (Request.Form) in Chrome, FF, and IE...nothing in Safari.

Answer (score 0):

Its works for me too.. I'm using IIS 6.0, i have done.

Run as administrator 'command prompt' then

cd c:\inetPub

Cd adminScripts

cscript adsutil.vbs get w3svc/NTAuthenticationProviders

cscript adsutil.vbs set w3svc/NTAuthenticationProviders "NTLM"

restart the IIS.