# ViewModel and FormCollection are empty on post

Tags: ios, asp.net-mvc-4, safari

I'm working with ASP.NET MVC and I'm trying to make my web project working under IPad with IOS7 and Safari browser.

My issue is only under IPAD, when I'm testing under IE9-10 chrome or Firefox everything works:
After submiting a form to the server, I return a new form.
When I want to post my new form, my ViewModel and FormCollection are empty.

The weird part begins: if I refresh my current page or press the back button on safari, my post works and fills ViewModel(and FormCollection).

Here is my code :

Client code:

```
     @using (Html.BeginForm("AnswerFeedback", "Customer", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "QuestionForm" }))
            {
                @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.IDQuizz)
                @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.IDFeedbackReporting)
                @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ActualQuestion.Type)
                @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ActualQuestion.ID)

                ....


                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4 col-xs-4 col-xs-offset-4 text-center">
                        <input type="submit" id="saveCustomerFeedBack" class="btn btn-primary btn-large btn-block" value="@Html.TextLocalized(2031, "Next", (int)Model.IDLangue)" />
                    </div>
                </div>  
              }
```

Server code:

```
   [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult AnswerFeedback(QuizzFeedbackViewModel viewModel)
    {
       // my viewModel contains null fields and formCollection is empty

        FormCollection formCollection = new FormCollection(this.HttpContext.Request.Form);

        int? nextQuestionID = ValidateQuestion(viewModel);

        if (nextQuestionID == null)
            return RedirectToAction("FeedBackDone", new { IDFeedBackReporting = viewModel.IDFeedbackReporting });
        return RedirectToAction("AnswerFeedback", new { IDFeedBackReporting = viewModel.IDFeedbackReporting, nextQuestionID = nextQuestionID, viewModel.QuizzName });
    }
```

Comment: Could there be some device dependent javascript firing and interrupting the post action?

Comment: The post action is not interrupting, my action in controller is called . Only form data is missed.

Comment: I have seen it before. In those cases it was an IIS configuration: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15528451/jquery-ajax-working-in-ie-chrome-and-ff-but-not-safari-server-using-mvc-4

Comment: Thank you for your answer but my IIS configuration is already set to Windows authentification and I removed Negociate (NTML is my unique provider).